# Hangouts on Windows 7 doesn't sign in

Tags: windows-7, google-hangouts

I've installed Google+ Hangouts on my Windows 7. When I run it, window with "Sign in" button appears.
Pressing on this button leads to nothing: no errors appear, no actions, no changes. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This was because in Google Chrome browser I haven't signed in. After setting up google account in Chrome browser settings, hangouts started working.

Comment: Yes you are right and you must have to running your chrome browser in background othervise hangout will also close.